# How to simulate passing the keyword to a website from a search engine?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

We made a website using the sitecore. And we have a rule for the DMS part when searching keyword contains SUV, then we do something. But my question is how to test this rule, we have prepared everything for the back-end. How to pass a keyword 'suv' to our website to  simulate  the search engine?

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own page simulating search engine (or just a page with a link to your app and open it with the SUV keyword - `http://mytestengine/index.html?q=SUV`) and navigate from this page to your Sitecore application. You must also add a new **engine** definition to your configuration:

```
<engine hostname="www.google" parametername="q"/>
<engine hostname="mytestengine" parametername="q"/>
```

Remember to clear the history of the browser before testing the solution - in other case your visit won't be considered as a new visit.

More information can be found in [the blog post](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/Identifying-Search-Engines-and-Search-Terms-with-the-Sitecore-Customer-Engagement-Platform.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have used the Tamper Data Firefox plugin to test some DMS functionality.  The plugin will allow you to intercept the request to your website and update the referrer to be: `http://www.google.com?q=suv`.

Steps:

1. Open page that has a link to your website in Firefox.
2. Open Tamper Data Plugin.
3. Select 'Start Tamper'.
4. Click link to your site.
5. When prompted, select 'Tamper'.
6. Change 'Referrer' field to: `http://www.google.com?q=suv` (or whichever search engine you'd like to test).